# 'DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock.WindowsLiveClient' does not contain a definition for 'ProcessUserAuthorizationAsync'

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I am trying to get the dotnetopenauth oauth2 "windows live" example to work that is shown here:
https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/tree/master/samples/OAuthClient

In the WindowsLive.aspx.cs page these two lines do not work:

```
windowsLiveClient.ProcessUserAuthorizationAsync

windowsLiveClient.PrepareRequestUserAuthorizationAsync
```

When I run the page it shows the error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock.WindowsLiveClient' does  
not contain a definition for 'ProcessUserAuthorizationAsync' and no extension method 
'ProcessUserAuthorizationAsync' accepting a first argument of type 
'DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock.WindowsLiveClient' could be found (are you missing a 
using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I am using the dotnetopenauth ultimate 4.3.1.13153 dll.

I also put these three files, that I got from the DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock folder, in my app_code folder:

```
IOAuth2Graph.cs
WindowsLiveClient.cs
WindowsLiveGraph.cs
```

I apologize for being a beginner. I have spent a few days trying a million different things and I can't get past this.

Comment: did u find a workaround for this..?